# c# linq how to declare in SQL Server and save date and time separately

Tags: c#, linq

I want to know :

1. which type is proper in SQL Server to declare date and time separately?
2. how to save date and time in these fields by linq?

Before I used:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")  
DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.ff tt")
```

But now when I use:

```
date date  
time time(7)
```

in SQL Server, I get

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime?

Comment: I've always use DateTime objects and not strings for my SQL in C#.

Answer (score 5):

Stop `ToString`ing your DateTimes.. Just pass `DateTime` to it. And in the database, if you are using SQL Server, use `datetime2` for a one-to-one compatibility to .NET.

Comment: thank you, is it store date and time separately? i have ti different field: date and time.

Comment: @mohammadadibi, I would just store both date and time in the same field. There's no caveat at doing this. If you insist and storing them separately, it's not a problem too.